# The use of length function of array in code

Tags: arrays

What is the difference between "array.length" and "array.length()" ?
If it's a bad question, forgive me.
I am asking this because I am making a lot of mistakes regarding this.
Thanks in advance.
(In Java language)

Comment: For which language?

Comment: In Java language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array.length property is used to get the length of array. If you are confused between length and length() then:

1. length property is used with array and objects in java
2. length() function is used with strings in java

Comment: I meant to ask for java. I think I am using both "array.length" and "array.length()" in java. I don't know which one to use. So, I correct my code only when I see an error.

Comment: ok, so if you are asking specifically about java then .length property is available for array and objects. If you are looking to find the length of string then you need to use .length()

for more info, see this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/length-vs-length-java/

Comment: Also I have edited my answer more clearly for java.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you very much. You were a great assistance.

Comment: If you think this solved your problem, please accept my answer.

Answer (score -1):

array.length and array.length() both are language specific. Both returns the length of array but some languages like java use array.length() while languages like javascript uses array.length property.